# Applying JsonMediaTypeFormatter to Json

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have the following formatter

```
 JsonMediaTypeFormatter formatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter();
 formatter.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore;
 formatter.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
 formatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
```

I would like to apply this formatting when serializing an object

```
 var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, formatter);
```

However, I am getting an error stating

```
 Cannot convert from System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter to Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting
```

Comment: Error is self explanatory. You are using Newtonsoft Jsonconvert which is expecting different object for formatting specification, but you are passing native. Net object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following, it works fine in my case:

```
// Create a Serializer with specific tweaked settings, like assigning a specific ContractResolver

    var newtonSoftJsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore, // Ignore the Self Reference looping
        PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.None, // Do not Preserve the Reference Handling
        ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(), // Make All properties Camel Case
        Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented
    };

// To the final serialization call add the formatter as shown underneath

var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj,newtonSoftJsonSerializerSettings.Formatting);
```

**Or**

```
 var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj,Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

In actual code this is how we use the `Json serializer` with specific settings, for a MVC project, using the `newtonSoftJsonSerializerSettings` created above:

```
  // Fetch the HttpConfiguration object
  HttpConfiguration jsonHttpconfig = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;    

// Add the Json Serializer to the HttpConfiguration object
    jsonHttpconfig.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = newtonSoftJsonSerializerSettings;

    // This line ensures Json for all clients, without this line it generates Json only for clients which request, for browsers default is XML
    jsonHttpconfig.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
```

Thus all the `Http requests` are serialized using the same serializer (newtonSoftJsonSerializerSettings)

Comment: Here, you are only passing .Formatting to SerializeObject. It still doesnt change to camelcase.

Comment: As I have shown that part which is giving you error is just a formatter, which will be corrected by my code, for remaining part, you need to hook the custom serializer for all the request, before serialization happens

Comment: I am plugging the serializer to the `System.Net.Http.Formatting` type, when what you have in the `JsonConvert` call is the `Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting`, both have different purpose, Newtonsoft is subset of overall Net Http formatter

Comment: Check the constructor of the `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`, post `Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented`, you can supply `JsonSerializerSettings`, which will pretty much do what you are expecting, this shall help you solve all possible cases